# Copy text file to usb zebra printer

Tags: windows, printing, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

First time using ZPL, I was googling my question but nothing so far.

I have downloaded the ZPL II programming language pdf file, and try to print the first sample:

```
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDTesting^FS
^XZ
```

I already create the txt file with above code, but when trying to "Copy" to the printer nothing happens.

by `copying to the printer` I found this: `copy printtest.txt usb1` or `copy printtest.txt > usb1`

but that doesn't work.

I got a Zebra Printer Model S4M, connected thru usb: port: `USB001` description: `Virtual printer port for usb`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its pretty simple to get it to print...
firstly share your printer
copy the the file to the shared printer path example  \Zebra1

i found some VB code i used a while back hope it helps

```
            Dim tempFile As New IO.StreamWriter("Name of file")
            Dim PrnPath as string ="\\MY-PC\Zebra"
            IO.File.Copy(tempFileName, PrnPath, True)
```

Comment: hey @Yugz thanks for the reply, I have also found this link which works great using c# `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us`. But I thought it was a DOS way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: awesome i'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple in C#:

```
if (File.Exists(inputFilePath))
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(inputFilePath, printerPath);
}
else
{
    //no file. 
}
```

where:
 - inputFilePath - path to ZPL file (special extension is not required); 
 - printerPath - path to shared(!) printer, for example: \127.0.0.1\zebraGX